# Hybridisation in Molecular Orbital Theory

Tags: physical-chemistry

How loosely can the term hybridisation be incorporated while constructing molecular orbitals? Does hybridisation hold any significance when looking at molecules through the Molecular Orbital Theory?

Answer (score 1):

Hybridisation is a convenient tool for chemical interpretation of bonding situations, and thus people like to use it for explaining or even predicting stuff.

From a purely theoretical point of view, you don't really need it. You could construct your basis set by building hybrid orbitals from the atomic orbitals, as some kind of initial guess. Also localization of the resulting molecular orbitals may give something similar to hybrid orbitals. But all this won't change the total energy or the actual electronic wave function of your system. It is just a unitary transformation leaving the final result invariant.